# TBB concurrent unordered map causes segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, tbb, concurrenthashmap

I need to implement a huge hash table which supports multiple threads to insert and get at the same time. The keys are int and the second elements are vectors of object T.

```
class T { 
        //class definitions here
}
```

Currently the implementation is helped with tbb::concurrent_unordered_map. On the documentation it seems to allow insertion and traversal at the same time. However, running with multiple pthreads will lead to segmentation fault although sequential test is perfectly fine. Note that there is definitely no erase or pop operations, i.e. the hash table is only allowed to grow.

```
std::vector<T*> get(int key) {
        //Note that the hash table hashTable is shared by multiple threads
        tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, std::vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
        if (it != hashTable.end())
                return it->second;
        else {
                std::vector<T*> newvector;
                return newvector;
        }
}

void insert(int key, T *t) {
        tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, std::vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
        if (it != hashTable.end())
                it->second.push_back(t);
        else {
                std::vector<T*> newTs;
                newTs.push_back(t);
                hashTable.insert(it, makepair(key, newTs));
        }
}
```

To debug what happened, I first changed std::vector to tbb::concurrent_vector, and then modify the function get() and insert() as follows.

```
std::vector<T*> get_test(int key) {
        std::vector<T*> test;
        //Note that the hash table hashTable is shared by multiple threads
        tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, tbb::concurrent_vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
        if (it != hashTable.end())
                test.insert(test.end(), it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
        for (T* _t : test)
                if (!_t)
                        printf("Bug happens here!\n"); //Segfault is originated here because a NULL is returned in the vector  
        return test;
}

void insert_test(int key, T *t) {
        //Here t is guaranteed to be not NULL
        if(!t)
                std::terminate();
        tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, tbb::concurrent_vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
        if (it != hashTable.end())
                it->second.push_back(t);
        else {
                std::vector<T*> newTs;
                newTs.push_back(t);
                hashTable.insert(it, makepair(key, newTs));
        }
}
```

Now we can see the reason that the parallel program crashes is some NULL pointer is returned in get_test() function. Recall that in insert_test() function NULL is never inserted as the second elements.

The following are the questions to ask.

(1) I read from somewhere that concurrent insertion in tbb::concurrent_unordered_map may cause some of the insertion attempt failed and then the temp objects is destroyed. Is this the reason that NULL is observed in get_test() function?

(2) Can TBB really allow insertion and traversal at the same time? This means while some threads are inserting, the others might call get() at the same time.

(3) Is there any better implementation, i.e. better concurrent hash table that support concurrent insert and read?

---

As @for_stack suggested, I have verified the second elements are concurrent_vectors and the entire program is runnable. A further test is conducted as follows:

```
tbb::concurrent_vector<T*> get_test(int key) {
            tbb::concurrent_vector<T*> test;
            //Note that the hash table hashTable is shared by multiple threads
            tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, tbb::concurrent_vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
            if (it != hashTable.end())
                    test = it->second;
            int i = 0;
            for (T* _t : test)
                    if (!_t)
                            i++;
            if (i > 0)
                    printf("%d of %lu Ts are NULL\n", i, test.size()); //Segfault is originated here because a NULL is returned in the vector  
            return test;
}

void insert_test(int key, T *t) {
        //Here t is guaranteed to be not NULL
        if(!t)
                std::terminate();
        tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, tbb::concurrent_vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
        if (it != hashTable.end())
                it->second.push_back(t);
        else {
                tbb::concurrent_vector<T*> newTs;
                newTs.push_back(t);
                hashTable.insert(it, make_pair(key, newTs));
        }
}
```

The output is

```
1 of 2 Ts are NULL
```

This means not all objects (T) returned in get() are NULL.

---

Again the sequential (or even 1 thread) running is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>TBB **CAN** support concurrent insertion and traversal for `concurrent_xxx` containers.</del> However, your original code has race conditions:

```
std::vector<T*> get(int key) {
    // other code
    return it->second;  # race condition 1
    // other code
}
```

The `get` function try to return a copy of `vector<T*>` (*read*), while other threads might call `insert` to modify the `vector<T*>` (*write*).

```
void insert(int key, T *t) {
    // other code
    it->second.push_back(t);   # race condition 2
    // other code
}
```

The `insert` function try to modify the `vector<T*>` with no lock guard. If there are several threads call `insert` at the same time (*multiple write*), OOPS!

`concurrent_unordered_map` only has safe guarantee for container operations, while it has no guarantee for operations on the `mapped_value`. You have to do it yourself.

Just as what you've tried, you can replace the `vector<T*>` with `concurrent_vector<T*>`. However, the new code you posted doesn't compile, you have to modify the implementation of `insert_test`:

```
void insert_test(int key, T *t) {
    //Here t is guaranteed to be not NULL
    if(!t)
            std::terminate();
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, tbb::concurrent_vector<T*>>::iterator it = hashTable.find(key);
    if (it != hashTable.end())
            it->second.push_back(t);
    else {
            // std::vector<T*> newTs;   # this is wrong!
            tbb::concurrent_vector<T*> newTs;
            newTs.push_back(t);
            hashTable.insert(it, make_pair(key, newTs));  // it should be make_pair not makepair
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your explanation. I used to think TBB will automatically apply a lock for concurrent insertion to the same key. However, the above code looks more like a pseudocode and in actual implementation the second element is indeed tbb::concurrent_vector, and the entire program crashes after longer time (than using std::vector). The reason is stated above as some NULL pointers are returned in get(), and I don't think changing the return type of get() to concurrent_vector will even help. Maybe I should edit the code so as not to cause any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

"TBB CAN support concurrent insertion and traversal for concurrent_xxx containers." - not exactly. Traversal is a tricky thing when there is no memory reclamation support like in TBB and concurrent erasure is supported by a container (`concurrent_hash_map`). However, `concurrent_unordered_map` does not support thread-safe `erase()` and thus thread-safe traversal is supported.

Comment: Could you use some examples to show why "Traversal is a tricky thing when there is no memory reclamation support like in TBB"?

Answer (score 0):

@Anton my friend, the concurrent_unordered containers do support concurrent traversal and insertion; they're implemented as skip-lists.  In the non-multi case the result of the pointer swing is tested, and if it fails the search is started again from the point of insertion.

Now C++ may have changed in the last few weeks since I worked at Intel, but I think there are serious bugs in the original code:

```
if (it != hashTable.end())
        return it->second;          // return a copy???
else {
        std::vector<T*> newvector;  // this is stack-allocated
        return newvector;           // return a copy??
}
```

The return value is vector, not reference or pointer to vector, so you are going to get copies of the current contents as return values, and inserting into the copy will not change any vector that is in the set.  Maybe fix that, and make sure there is no asynchronous reference to a vector, and then look for remaining bugs.

Comment: Chris, Nice to see you here again! :)
We can say that "concurrent_unordered_xxx containers do support concurrent traversal and insertion" but we cannot say "concurrent_xxx containers do support concurrent traversal and insertion" - the diff is in this "unordered" part because `concurrent_hash_map` does not support safe traversal, not completely/not officially at least :) P.s. "split-ordered list"

Comment: Whoops!  Absolutely correct, Anton.  My oversight. Yep, split-ordered. That was a brain fart.